# Trigger email from landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I am sending an email for a couple of agents and my DE contains subscriberkey,emailaddress,agentemailaddress. I have a landing page where client's need to book an appointment with their respective agent.

I want to trigger an email to the agent with all the details of client's appointment as soon as they submit and the data inserted in DE.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide more details about your usecase? In general there are multiple ways to achieve the outcome.

Comment: We are running an email campaign for a particular location where two agents have been allocated based on the postcode. I have created a source data extension for the email campaign from accounts and associate respective agent based on the postcode. There's a landing page where customers can book an appointment (1-1) with the respective agent. I want to send an email to the agent as soon as customer submit the form on the landing page so that they get details of the customer and plan their schedule.

Comment: There are hidden input fields in the form containing agent's subscriberkey & email address in the form submitted by customers. So, I want to trigger an email to the agent with all the other details of the customer.

Comment: Were you able to implement what I have suggested?

Comment: We cannot use Journey builder as I am not gonna send an email to the customer but agent which a separate DE.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Journey builder?

You can follow below steps to send an email to a contact

1. Setup an Email
2. Create a journey using Journey builder and select the event as the change in DE
3. As the next action, select "send email" and select the email you previously created
4. Activate the Journey

System will automatically trigger an email, as soon as a contact is updated in DE.

Comment: I don't think there any event like 'Change in DE'. A Journey event can be fired only 2 ways - API or Scheduled.

Comment: You can create a new "Entry Source" based on your contact Data, which is related to a specific DE.

Comment: Yeah but that will not trigger an email immediately unless invoked my API

Comment: He is already updating the DE and you can set an entry criteria saying whenever a particular information is updated in the related DE, send an email to the customer.

Comment: That's what I am saying. We cannot send an email immediately after the update of a DE .. that's one of the biggest pain of Journey Builder .. to send an instant email, you'll have to use API to fire the source event

Comment: Probably we are missing each other's perspective on the current scenario. I am still not convinced when you say "You cannot send an immediate email using Journey". Ofcourse you will be breaking down it into pieces 1. Landing Page 2. Journey.

Comment: Give it a try and let me know :) . Requirement is to send an email to a contact as soon as it enters the source event DE..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55248/discussion-between-salesforcesmarty-and-maneesh).

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with AMPscript, this page has a great starting point:
https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/using_ampscript_with_the_web_service_api/create_a_triggered_send_using_ampscript_and_the_soap_web_service_api/

This page also has a breakdown of the code: https://etsalesforce.wordpress.com/triggered/

Comment: I don't really understand from where I should start to use AMPscript for this campaign. Can you help me if I provide an eg. of data I am sending from Form to DE?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a smart capture form, and as soon as someone fills up the form, triggered email can be sent out to respective agent.

Please see below link on the form:
https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/smart_capture/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a Landing Page, then the only way you have is to use AMPScript and Soap Webservice (as suggested by @eduardo)

Else, you can also use a SmartCapture form or CloudPages which will give you a direct option to send an email as soon as a record is entered into a DE

Comment: Think it as of a bigger use case, If he is sending email to pass landing Page URL to his customers, he should make it as a part of a customer journey to capture unique customer behaviour and engage them in personalised journeys.

Answer (score 0):

Lot's of ideas here, and unless you want to fire the event via the API there's really only one way I've found:

1) Upon form submit, use a triggered send definition to send the email
2) If there are journey requirements then use ampscript in the email in step one to insert a row into the entry DE
3) If there are engagement split requirements for the first email, you can overcome this with SQL Query and a tracking DE.